# Can this box with a shadow be built with CSS only (no images)?

Tags: html, css

I have the following design element and am having trouble making it work without making the big drop shadow without an image.

Is there a way to do it with only CSS?

*(Disregard the pattern in the background...that's just there to show that the shadow has some transparency.)*

[image]

Comment: Regardless of what you'd actually call it...I need to know how to pull it off with just CSS.

Comment: @Shpigford do u open to css3?

Comment: Are you limited to one `<div>`? Do you accept [CSS3 2D transform](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)? Do you accept [CSS3 3D transform](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d)?

Comment: No limits on HTML or CSS. Whatever it takes to pull it off. :)

Comment: you can give the below effect with box shadow

Comment: Have you tried http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple `box-shadow`-values can create this effect.

The issue here is the transparency; if you use a transparent color value for the color of the shadow they'll multiply into some sort of gradient and eventually become completely opaque.

Instead, create a pseudo-element with the same size and at the same position as the box and have the `box-shadow` drop from that element instead using a solid color. You can then give the pseudo-element an `opacity`-value which will also affect the shadow but (obviously) not the actual box.

The basic CSS could be something like:

```
.box {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.box:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  opacity: .25;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, -2px -2px 0 #000 /* and so on and so forth */; 
}
```

**[Here's an example](http://codepen.io/Mest/pen/pnlkx)** with some more extensive styling. Note that you don't need the static `width` and `height`-values, you could just let the `.box` automatically ajust its size according to its children.

Comment: You win the internet.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the general effect with multiple box shadows.

**[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/EsFep)**

However, the multiplying effects of rgba values preclude having the shadow having the opacity you seem to require.

I suppose a formula could be worked out so that the alpha channels could be so specified to solve that issue.

Comment: Why not replace 'lightblue' by something like rgba(150,150,150,.1)

Comment: It won't work because the alpha values multiply and the shadow gets more opaque. Try it.

Comment: The shadows don't transparent. And even if you use `x` shadows with `y` opacity then first will be with `x * y` opacity and the last will be with only `y` opacity.

Answer (score 0):

You can add shadows from skewed objects inside yours like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/smQfb/1/):

HTML:

```
<div class="box shadow">
    <div class="shadowTop"></div>
    <div class="shadowLeft"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: green;
}
.box {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 98px auto;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.shadowTop {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px -20px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transform: skewX(45deg);
}
.shadowLeft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: -20px -20px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transform: skewY(45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops, seems I'm too late. Still I want to share my solution.

I was very close to a one-`<div>` solution, but due to the fact that `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements are the content *on* that element, they can't stay "underneath" that element itself, so I have to resort to two-`<div>`s.

My solution (compare to Nils' accepted answer) has one advantage, that you don't need to specify that many `box-shadow` all through, and allows you to use units other than pixel to create that "shadow".

[Online Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/6694790)

```html
<div class="wrapper"><div class="content"></div></div>
```

```css
div.wrapper {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:10px;
    position:relative;
 }
 div.wrapper::before,
 div.wrapper::after {
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-40px;
    left:-40px;
    background-color:rgba(245,245,245,0.8);
    z-index:0;
    transform-origin:top left;
 }
 div.wrapper::before {
    width:45px;
    height:195px;
    border-top-left-radius:3px 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    transform:skewY(45deg);
 }
 div.wrapper::after {
    width:195px;
    height:45px;
    border-top-left-radius:10px 3px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    transform:skewX(45deg);
 }
 div.wrapper div.content {
    position:relative;
    border-radius:10px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#CCF;
    z-index:1;
 }
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

The trick is to transform two pseudo elements to create the illusion of shadow.

I intentionally used a blue box to stand out of the background. You can of course use whatever color you like.

Note, that there're something to pay attention to:

1. dabblet.com provides prefix-free JS library by default. You'll either have to embed that library, or add back prefix on your code;
2. Firefox used a ["non-standard" prefixed version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-bottom-left-radius#Browser_compatibility) of single-corner radius in history.